# What to do with CSS prefix questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

Throughout the time I've been on SO I've run into numerous questions that can all be fixed by adding the relevant browser prefixes (`-webkit-`, `-moz-`, etc.) for the `animation` and `transition` properties in particular.

In my first month or so on SO I loved seeing these questions because they meant (nearly) free rep, but as time has gone on I've gotten quite tired of answering them because each answer is nearly the same, but there is currently no other way dealing with them that I'm aware of. I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25108393/svg-not-working-in-chrome/25109123#25109123) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25108699/css-animation-of-svg-fill-ie-issues/25109023#25109023) just today.

Most questions with this issue essentially say, `"why isn't this working on X browser?"`. It seems to me that they aren't duplicate *questions*, but all have the *same answer*, namely `"Add ________ prefixes to the ________ property"`. If they are considered duplicates, is there a base question that I can close them duplicates of?

I'd *like* to close them as a `simple typographical error` because that's how it seems to me as a more experienced developer, but I don't think it's a typographical error for  someone just learning.

So how should we handle questions like these? Can we make a canonical question/answer to cover these prefix issues into one post and then be able to close these questions as duplicates? If a canonical question is the best solution, what is the actual question?

Comment: Can't you just close them as duplicates then?

Comment: A canonical answer sounds good. It would need to list the browsers (as these questions typically go "It does not work on Xxx"), and the list of commands that need a prefix.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I suppose that's my question. Should I? If so, which one should be used?

Comment: Zach, at a quick glance I don't think any question you answered yourself (so far, huh huh) is broad *enough* for a canonical duplicate. Try come up with an answer if a post asked "Which CSS properties require what prefixes on which browser?" (If asked before on SO, it may have been closed for being too broad.)

Comment: I'll write a canonical dup.

Comment: People keep asking them because people like you keep answering them -.- So, "how should we handle questions like these?" _Stop answering two per day for the love of Cthulhu!_

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The entire point of the question is to find an alternate solution to answering them...

Comment: Yeah I'm just trying to make it as clear as possible that continuing to answer them after _a year and a half_, especially when you've already figured out that there is a problem here, is bad and wrong.

Comment: Are you only concerned about CSS, or should the canonical answer cover stuff like eg. `requestFullscreen` vs `mozRequestFullScreen`/`msRequestFullscreen`/`webkitRequestFullscreen`?

Comment: @robertc The original intention of the question was solely related to CSS properties and values

Answer (score 14):

[Why doesn't [CSS feature] work in [browser] but works in others?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25110510/3890059)

Here's the canonical dup!

Close all questions completely solvable with vendor prefixes as a duplicate of this.

Comment: Shouldn't we make it a community question/answer? There are several improvements that need to be made to your answer :)

Comment: @ZachSaucier Ok, I made it community wiki.

Comment: Closing all questions solvable with vendor prefixes as a duplicate of a artificial question written for a generic treatise of prefixes? That would phase out specific information that may have been posted about the need for prefixes, for a particular property or value and for particular browsers.

Comment: If we're going to have canonical duplicates, then create them by editing the original question and answer (i.e. the one that isn't a duplicate), not by creating yet another duplicate.

Comment: @Alohci: That depends on whether it is even possible to find a question that can be edited in a way that will not compromise the context of existing answers. Sometimes it helps to start with a clean slate - and for that, creating a new duplicate (so to speak) would be just fine, provided the new Q&A pair is high quality. In general, duplicates should point to earlier questions, but exceptions can be made and occasionally are.

Comment: @BoltClock- Why would a answer be considered good in the context of an original question, but not in the context of its supposed duplicate. IMHO, there's something wrong about closing questions based on the principle that they have the same answer as another, different, question since it precludes those kind of correct-in-context answers from being added.

Comment: I have to agree with @JukkaK.Korpela -- the title of the question is bad, and posting a contrived duplicate is not productive. We're a Q&A site that receives hundreds (thousands?) of new questions a day, I am skeptical that an **organic** question with salvageable content does not exist as BoltClock and bjb568 suggest. If this is asked frequently enough to merit this level of attention and a canonical answer, surely it isn't necessary to contrive it.

Answer (score 0):

They should be answered by telling that some browsers support only a vendor-prefixed version of a name or value and showing the prefixed version(s) and citing a good reference (MDN is usually OK).

If there is an existing question about the same property or value, with an approved or upvoted answer, then the question should be closed as a duplicate, as usual.

If desired, you can also point to some general treatise on vendor prefixes. But such a treatise is not an answer; it is just additional reading that might explain the background in a useful way.

But each property or value is still a separate issue, especially from the viewpoint of people who ask the questions, but also technically: the prefixes needed may vary, or prefixes might not affect the problem at all. We should not try to engineer a fictional question, fitted to match a particular treatise we have in our mind – especially since this may lead to a serious mismatch between a question and the answer(s).

A generic question (implicitly universally quantified question) like “Why doesn't [feature] work in [browser]?” surely has very different correct answers depending on “feature” (and on “browser”). If the answer is completely wrong for the question “Why doesn’t `display: dwim` work in Chrome?”, “Why doesn’t `calc()` work in IE 8?”, or millions of other questions of the same pattern, then it is not a correct answer to “Why doesn't [feature] work in [browser]?”.

Comment: Two examples that come to mind where the answer isn't as straightforward as "you forgot your prefixes": gradients and flexbox, both of which have gone through *multiple* complete rewrites in both their definitions and their syntax. A case could also be made for transitions, especially given that [some browsers like Chrome have been found to have issues handling transitions with unknown properties, prefixed or not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22457222/ie10-11-uses-transform-webkit-transform/22457802#22457802).

Comment: @BoltClock But, yay community wiki, a canonical dup can have all that included!