# Is my canonical dup for Vanilla JS DOM Manipulation ok?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, canonical, needs-more-focus

[How can I manipulate the DOM without a library like jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29596357/2371861)

My question wasn't particularly well-recieved. There are 3 pending votes to close as a duplicate of [What do people mean by "DOM Manipulation" and how would I do that?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3934826/2371861) which I don't think is really related.

Is my question ok for this site? What can I do to improve it?

Comment: That's an extremely broad question, I don't think there's much you can do to improve it. It simply isn't a question fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I thot it was ok on the basis that it was a general reference question.

Comment: Eh? Why would you think that? When did Stack Overflow start accepting general reference questions?

Comment: You really couldn't find an existing question for that answer?

Comment: @Shog9 No… Non-general-reference questions aren't that broad.

Comment: I guess what I'm asking is... You couldn't find a more specific question where it was obvious that the asker (and anyone else with the same question) desperately needed an in-depth explanation of DOM manip? Because... If you couldn't... Then there's really no need for this "canon", is there...

Comment: I mean… the purpose of a canon dup isn't to answer one specific question… it's to answer a class or questions.

Comment: @bjb568 - It comes down to this: SO is not your blogging platform. You should come here to ask a question or to answer someone else's question, or to answer your own question (it took me 5 hours to figure this out, so I'm going to help the next person). You've been asked, and have so far failed, to show *who's* question you've answered. Anyone could make a broader question out of a bunch of specific questions, but who does that help? Reference questions are tricky. It's advisable to work with a group of other users before attempting them.

Comment: I'm positive contributions of this nature would be welcome at places like MDN, and that's because it's a reference wiki.

Comment: I think you might be working with a non-canonical definition of canonical here. This might help: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/

Comment: I think http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267634/what-to-do-with-css-prefix-questions was made to cover a *class* of questions anyway, and it seems to be doing its job.

Comment: @bjb568: Yes, but a quite restricted class of questions - and there are [actual questions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27606549/1048572) that could be closed. But no one asks "*how does the dom work?*"

Answer (score 3):

Sounds vaguely similar to a question [I asked a while ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/174013/191410).

Your goals are certainly respectable, but when creating a reference question you must still ask an on-topic question.

It can sometimes help to state very boldly at the top that you are creating a reference question, but in this case I don't think it'd help much. While the content is quite impressive, it's just far too broad for SO. I recommend you speak with a publisher about printing a book on the topic.

Occasionally you may run across an exception to the above "rule". There are several reasons why exceptions exist:

> 1. The question wasn't in violation of the sites rules when it was first posted. It was appropriate at the time it was created and has simply been allowed to stay despite the fact that the rules have changed.
> 2. Such exceptions are very, very rare, for a reason. Everyone likes to think that their post is worthy of an exception. In pretty much every single case, it's not.
> 3. Those exceptions that are made are almost always a result of a discussion on meta first, in which it's determined that the post in violation of the guidelines really is needed, and to ensure it has good content.
>
> [Asking the questions that dare not be asked... with answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174013/asking-the-questions-that-dare-not-be-asked-with-answer#comment519066_174016)

Comment: "but when creating a reference question you must still ask an on-topic question" That isn't the case with many reference and canonical questions that I've seen.

Comment: @bjb568 - Such as? See [this comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174013/asking-the-questions-that-dare-not-be-asked-with-answer#comment519066_174016)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3737139/2371861 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/2371861

Comment: @bjb568 - Those questions were written in 2010 and 2008, respectively. The guidelines for the site have changed significantly in the past 5 years. See the edit to my post.

Comment: @bjb568 - Also, your second example is not nearly as broad a topic as your question was. Just compare the size (and completeness) of that answer to yours.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11077857/2371861 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/12769982/2371861 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/9205083/2371861 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/12916539/2371861

Comment: @bjb568 - Can you honestly not see the difference between those questions and the one you asked, in light of what's already been said?

Comment: They're all off-topic for a regular question tho. The second one is especially broad.

Comment: @bjb568 - Yes, there are many, many, many examples of off-topic questions on SO that predate our current on-topicness rules, haven't been closed (*yet*) or are preserved for historical reference. That doesn't mean you should go and write one on purpose.

Comment: So can I use questions asked 2013 as an example? 2014?

Comment: @bjb568 Use [ask] (and linked articles) as your guide. Also, read the blog post Shog linked to.

Comment: @bjb568: The `too broad` close reason is "*There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format*". For canonical questions, this is lifted *a bit* - as there is only one, community-edited answer. However, that still must not grow too long while acquiring the necessary quality. If it does, splitting up in smaller topics is necessary; the canonical may still act as a faq-link reference (like the PHP symbol refence you linked).

Comment: I'd think that if it's easily under 30k, length shouldn't be a problem (if an answer is provided as in canonical dups, *asking* for somebody to write you a book is off-topic).

Comment: @bjb568 - One may as well create a canonical dup titled "How to program in Javascript" for all the simple newbie questions out there. But that completely defeats the purpose of SO. Your well-meaning attempt has been rejected. I know from experience that it stings, a LOT. (My attempt ended up with something like a -20 score before being deleted.) It's really for the best, though. When you've used the site for a few more years, you'll probably end up agreeing.